# Can you disable that annoying "blop blop" sound in volume?

Tags: sound

When I try to change volume on-fly, i always hear that annoying blop blop sound.

Not sure whose idea it was to make it default, but it's driving me nuts. Can I disable it?! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

'...the annoying blop blop sound...' what a wonderful description!
The following commands did it for me:

Tell the system to stop emitting the blop:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false`

Restart the audio service:

`pulseaudio -k`

PERMANENT SOLUTION:

The only solution I could find that accurately works seems to be to rename (or delete) the actual audio file used for the blop blop.

```
 sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/elementary/stereo/audio-volume-change.wav /usr/share/sounds/elementary/stereo/audio-volume-change.bak
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for mouse wheel changing, but sadly, doesn't work when using keyboard shortcut for volume +/- . Cannot believe they actually made TWO separate ways for these sounds to perform, argh.

Comment: I edited my answer with a better, yet more drastic option